# PHP, Validate if user entered an email domain, NOT address

Tags: php, validation, email, dns

I was looking for this answer, but I was not able to find this exact variation.

I'm looking for the following to validate:

```
#1)  @toysrus.com
#2)  @staples.com
#3)  @example.com
```

And the following NOT to validate:

```
#1)  staples.com
#2)  Randy@staples.com
#3)  @testcom
```

Basically, I want to force the user to enter a valid email domain, NOT an email address.  Any clue how I could go about this?

I guess alternatively ask a user for their website domain name and just append the '@' character to that, but it's more confusing.  It would be easier to simply to ask the user, please enter your company email domain name.

Thanks!

Comment: "I guess alternatively ask a user for their website domain name and just append the '@' character to that, but it's more confusing." I'd say that's much **less** confusing. No normal user is going to enter "@staples.com" when asked for their e-mail domain name. They're just going to put in `staples.com`. Your *best* bet is probably just asking for their full e-mail address, then parsing the domain out of that.

Comment: Normally I agree, but part of the functionality my web app provides for the user is the ability to restrict who can sign up for this service based on email domain, and any user purchasing this service should be aware of what that means, or they shouldn't be using that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression to match the email domain name.
For example:

```
$pattern = "^@(\w)+((\.\w+)+)$";
if (preg_match($pattern,$domain))
    echo "Domain name right"
```

"^@" means the string should start with "@"."(\w)+" match at least 1 number or letter."(.\w+)+" match at least 1 domain name,such as ".com" or ".edu.cn". "$" means the end of the string.

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying, but I am receiving an error with this code:  Warning (2): preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: Sorry,I hasn't run the code I write.I forgot add "/" at the begining and the end of $pattern,the pattern should be `$pattern = "/^@(\w)+((\.\w+)+)$/";` @user2278120

Comment: Thanks, it works now.  I accepted your answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a multi-stage process

```
$email = 'something@somedomain.com';
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // The email is a valid format so now we check the domain
    $domain = explode('@', $email);
    if(getmxrr($domain[1])) {
        // This is about as far as we can take it.
        // The email is valid and the domain has MX records
    }
}
```

Comment: OP clearly states the input would be `@somedomain.com`, not `something@somedomain.com`. `filter_var` simply won't work for this.

Comment: It's a LOT easier to ask them for an email address (which most people understand) and doing the leg work yourself vs. asking them for the domain that hosts their email (which is more likely to elicit incorrect responses).

Comment: Yes, and I agree - note my comment to the question itself. Still, if you're going to answer a question with "don't do it this way", you should at least note that your answer isn't doing what the user asked for.

Comment: I already knew how to do this, but my user will understand entering an email domain because of the nature of the service he is signing up for.